# C++ shared pointers referencing an object within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, smart-pointers

Only just started looking into smart pointers and how they can be used to improve efficiency within code and I'm curious as to how shared_ptr reacts with class objects within an array/vector/container.

From what i've read the general gist of shared pointers is that once all of them pointing to an object have been destroyed or reallocated, the object is also destroyed. However if our object is also stored within an array/vector, does the shared pointer still attempt to destroy the object even though it is still accessible.

Is there some way to set up shared pointers with arrays in mind so you can ensure that you only delete the objects once you go to clear your array/vector, or would you have to resort to using shared_ptr in your array as well?

Comment: You should give an example of what you mean for it to be "in an array/vector". But yes, if all the `shared_ptr`s go, it gets destroyed.

Comment: Yes there is, use an `array` or `vector` of `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: There is no way for `shared_ptr` to know that you have a copy lying around in an array.

Comment: Are you really sure you need shared_ptrs in the first place? Have you measured a significant performance improvement?

Comment: You should really make up a short code sample of what you mean. Your plain prose is ambiguous regarding @JosephMansfield's points.

Comment: the example I was thinking of was that of a a* example where you would have a array/vector of tiles , but during path finding and creating your path you would need pointers to your previous tile in the path. If once your done with your path you've cleared all the pointer references of the tile, it was whether that cause you still had it in a tile list, that it would have prevented it being deleted.  Overall now that i've thought more on it, this isnt the place for shared pointers as I need to still maintain the list and clear it separately.

Comment: Shared pointers are all about ownership of the object. If an object is part of another object, then it is owned by that other object. It doesn't make sense to have a second entity that tries to own it too.

Comment: Yeah, think it's more relevant to use raw pointers for these type of references and just ensure that when it comes to ending the program, be it intentionally or by exceptions that i clear them accordingly instead of trying to rely on smart pointers handling everything

Comment: isn't weak_ptr made for this, because it holds a non-owning reference?

Comment: @Incubbus yes and no. A weak_ptr won't increment the reference count, but it's also designed to allow a graceful fail if the object it points to gets deallocated. It doesn't prevent the object from being deallocated, so you still have to check that it's valid before using it.

Answer (score 3):

Mixing naked references with a shared_ptr is to be discouraged. The main reason is because it breaks the reference count concept, which is what the shared_ptr uses to determine when it is safe to deallocate the referenced object. Any naked references *must* have a shorter lifetime than the longest-living shared_ptr, otherwise a crash is brewing.

If you want to contain a set of objects in a container of some sort, and still be able to access those objects using a shared_ptr, it's best to use an array/vector/container of shared_ptr's, as this brings the container "into the fold" so to speak with the shared_ptr concept. This has the benefit that, when the object is removed from the container, it will not be immediately deallocated, and vice-versa with the shared pointers referencing it.

The downside of using a container of shared_ptrs is that it makes pointer math slightly more difficult since you are, in effect, working with a kind of pointer to a pointer.

Comment: So are you passing around shared_ptr copies or references? How does it do reference counting if there are many shared_ptr objects?

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of question I was looking for, been trying to look at how I can implement smart pointers to prevent issues with say exceptions that could lead to resource leaks and in a way have got a bit carried away with them before I've got a full grasp on them

Comment: @snowandotherjoys The implementation varies, but often shared_ptr objects use a static object to keep track of reference counts between instances.

Answer (score 2):

You are expected to use shared pointers in only two ways:

1) When you create a new object,

```
std::shared_ptr<something> ptr(new something);
```

2) When you copy a shared pointer to another.

```
std::shared_ptr<something> copy(ptr);
```

So, if you create an object in an array, it won't fit the shared pointer scheme.

If you want to save an object allocated using a shared pointer in a vector, then you've got to save its shared pointer:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<something> > my_vector;

my_vector.push_back(new something);
```

When you clear your vector, all the pointers get cleared and thus objects that were only referenced by the vector get deleted:

```
my_vector.clear();  // do "delete something" as required
```

---

As a side note, you say "more efficient" in your question... Shared pointers are not more efficient and they are not unlikely to create more code in your software than you would otherwise think of.

One very important point in C++ are exceptions. Objects saved in smart pointers (unique_ptr works too in that case) will automatically get deleted on exceptions. This is very important. For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<something> ptr(new something);

...
if(this_is_true) throw std::logic_error("something's wrong");
...
```

In the code above, the pointer `ptr` automatically gets deleted before the throw returns. This is not what I would call more efficient, but much better in terms of cleanliness. If you call a function that can throw (i.e. another `new` for example) then it becomes very tedious to handle each call (i.e. you'd need to have a try/catch around every single call and the catch would have to delete the pointers and then rethrow.)

So in that sense, it is efficient. However, in terms of speed of execution, it is probably not any faster (or slower) than not using shared pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for pointers to subobjects - array elements or object members - to share ownership with pointers to the whole object. You create `shared_ptr`s to subobjects with the template constructor:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

It accepts a `shared_ptr` of any type, and a pointer (possibly completely unrelated) to the target type. The constructed `shared_ptr` shares ownership with the source object `r` but when dereferenced points at `ptr`.

For example, create a pointer to the third array element of a `std::array`:

```
class foo {};
auto array = std::make_shared<std::array<foo, 16>>();
auto element_ptr = std::shared_ptr<foo>(array, array->data() + 2);
```

or to an object's data member:

```
struct foo {
  int i;
};
auto some_foo = std::make_shared<foo>();
auto foo_member = std::shared_ptr<int>(some_foo, &some_foo->i);
```

It's a shame there's no handy type-deducing "make" function like `std::make_shared` for this, it's annoying to explicitly specify the type of the subobject. Maybe we should write our own:

```
template <typename Object, typename SubObject>
inline std::shared_ptr<SubObject>
make_sub_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<Object>& c, SubObject* ptr) {
    return {c, ptr};
}
```

so we can simplify the earlier creations to:

```
auto element_ptr = make_sub_ptr(array, array->data() + 2);
// ...
auto foo_member = make_sub_ptr(some_foo, &some_foo->i);
```

**[Live Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6b87f57c16ed9a6)**